# I can not boot my own OS with a USB on my Mac

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-16, bootloader

So, I have created a simply assembly bootloader:

```
    cli
hang:
    jmp hang

    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    db 0x55
    db 0xAA
```

I have compiled it with NASM to a binary on my Mac terminal and started it with QEMU. It worked.  So I decided to create a boot stick with balenaEtcher. I've tried it but when I'm starting my Mac and press alt by stick isn't displaying on the screen. I've tried several USB-Sticks and Ports and created a Usb stick with dd. Nothing worked. Can you tell me what I have done wrong? 
Using MacOS Mojave...

Comment: Possibly your mac does not support legacy boot.  I'm not sure though.

Comment: Some guides on the internet suggests that legacy boot is only enabled on mac if a partition table with a valid active partition is found.  Perhaps try to add such a dummy partition.

Comment: Are you sure you want to develop a legacy-BIOS bootloader on Mac hardware?  How much legacy IBM-PC / BIOS emulation do Macs even have?  (On "regular" PCs, the chipset + firmware emulates a legacy PIT timer and other legacy i/o port stuff, but Intel has said they plan to remove support for that in some upcoming hardware generation around 2020, leaving just UEFI.  So now is not a great time to sink effort into learning already-obsolete ways of booting.)